# Tried to create a discord bot to react to messages, but nothing happened

Tags: python, bots, discord

I want to create a bot that reacts all messages (using emotes from the default_emojis and custom_emojis lists) from a specific user in my server, wherever he posts the message.

I looked through a few outdated tutorials, and even a question that was asked here about a year ago, and I ended up trying this, but nothing really happened in the server. The bot would be online but wouldn't react to anything.

This is the code I used:

```
import discord
from discord.ext    import commands
from discord.ext.commands   import Bot
import asyncio

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

async def on_ready():
    print ("welcome_msg")


default_emojis = [
    "\N{GRINNING FACE}",
]

custom_emojis = [
    "staylovesmall"
]

async def react(message):
    for emoji in default_emojis:
        await message.add_reaction(emoji)
    for emoji in message.guild.emojis:
        if emoji.name in custom_emojis:
            await message.add_reaction(emoji)

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id == "user_id":
        await react(message)

bot.run("<Bot ID here>")
```

Using `if message.author.id == "<the user's id>" :` breaks the bot, but using

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    if "react to me" in message.content.lower():
        await react(message)
```

I have very limited knowledge of python and anything beyond lists and tuples is Ancient Greek to me. 
Any ideas what's going on? Thanks a lot!

EDIT: I replaced the str to int, and I tried adding text emotes (e.g. :regional_indicator_a:) This gives me this error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Kailash Seshadri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Kailash Seshadri\Desktop\React\bot.py", line 39, in on_message
    await react(message)
  File "C:\Users\Kailash Seshadri\Desktop\React\bot.py", line 31, in react
    await message.add_reaction(emoji)
  File "C:\Users\Kailash Seshadri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\message.py", line 928, in add_reaction
    await self._state.http.add_reaction(self.channel.id, self.id, emoji)
  File "C:\Users\Kailash Seshadri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 225, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 BAD REQUEST (error code: 10014): Unknown Emoji
```

The code is:

```
default_emojis = [
    "\N{GRINNING FACE}",
    "\U0001F606"

    "\U0001F1F8"
]
```

The first two on their own work fine, but when I add the letter in position 3, the error shows up and both the 2 Unicode emotes don't register. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: `message.author.id` will be an integer, not a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @Patrick Haugh said: Discord snowflakes (like `author.id`)  have become integers in v1.0. [(documentation)](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#snowflakes-are-int)

So the piece of code you have to adjust is the following:

Assuming the user you want to check for has the id "123".

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id == 123: # removed the quotes here
        await react(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

As to solving the emoji issue, I reccomend using copy-pasted emoji instead of unicode strings.
Emojipedia is a great resource for this.